# Making a call to an API with nested data, getting "TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, backend, rake

I am making a react app with a call to an API in a rails backend that I would like to seed into the data base, the API returns

```
{
   "_id": "5e96659e6a66e65486e24493",
   "content": "And I knew exactly what to do. But in a much more real sense, I had no idea what to do.",
   "character": {
     "_id": "5e93b4a43af44260882e33b0",
     "firstname": "Michael",
     "lastname": "Scott",
     "__v": 0
   },
   "__v": 0
 }
```

I want to grab the content and the character, along with the first and last name and seed that in my data base to be called on in my front end.
currently in my backend I have a table migration

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.string :character

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have a controller

```
    before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @questions = Question.all

    render json: @questions, only: [:content, :character, :id]
  end

end
```

and in my seed file

```
require 'rest-client'

 resp = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get,
 url: "https://officeapi.dev/api/quotes/",
 headers:{
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 })

resp_array = JSON.parse(resp)

resp_array.each do |question|
    Question.create(
       id: question["id"],
       content: question["content"],  
       character: question["character"]
    )
end
```

and the schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_09_29_183742) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "content"
    t.string "character"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

I thought this would work but when I went to run rake db:seed I get a "TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer"
I believe this is because of the nested id,firstname,lastname in the character hash or an incorrect way Ive set this up. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There could also be an issue because the id returned from the API ("5e96659e6a66e65486e24493") is a string, and the id column in your database would be an integer type. Maybe save the id from the API in a separate column (guid?).

After that, there is a chance the nested character fields would also cause a problem. You could serialize the hash, but my suggestion would to have characters stored in a separate table. The two tables could look like:

```
quotes
------
id
guid
content
character_id

characters
----------
id
guid
first_name
last_name
```

Comment: Thank you! with these separate tables would I have to create a belongs_to table relationship?

Comment: Yep, a quote `belongs_to` a character, and a character `has_many` quotes.